# exclude model from getting affected by light in libgdx 3D

Tags: libgdx

I have 2 objects in the 3d scene. I would like the light to affect only 1, and leave the other one unaffected How does one instruct the light to do that? I am using pointLight. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't specify the environment in the call to render for models you don't want to be affected by light. See also: https://xoppa.github.io/blog/loading-a-scene-with-libgdx/